# pivot table for count values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
ColA    ColB
abc      1
abc      0
efj      1
efj      1
hij      1
hej      1
```

I want to make a pivot table so that it can display like this:

```
Count of ColA   Column Labels   
Row Labels                 0    1
abc                        1    1
efj                             2
hej                             1
hij                             1
Grand Total                1    5
```

While making the same in a spreadsheet pivot table, the column "ColA" will go to the "ROWS", "ColB" will go to "Columns" and "values". The "Values" will have 
"Count of ColB".

In order to do the same in pandas, I did the following:

```
pd.pivot_table(train_filtered, index=["ColA"], values = ["ColB"], aggfunc = [np.count])
```

However, there is nothing called count for aggregate function in pandas. Is there anyway that similar thing can be achieved?

**EDIT**

Rewriting the output as the one shown is having lots of ambiguity:

```
    ColB    
ColA    0   1
abc     1   1
efj         2
hij         1
hej         1
```

Comment: Mind explaining your output a bit? It doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Sure, thank you for asking. Its a aggregation of ColA. For each unique value in ColA, we need to summate the values in ColB.

Comment: See my answer. I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow found the answer from this link - [Pandas pivot table for multiple columns at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165629/pandas-pivot-table-for-multiple-columns-at-once)

```
(df.set_index('ColA')
 .groupby(level='ColA')
 .apply(lambda g: g.apply(pd.value_counts))
 .unstack(level=1)
 .fillna(0))
```

This works fine for me and gives the exact answer that i was looking for.