# How to calculated pivot table using python

Tags: python, pivot

I have a sample table below:

```
Temperature Voltage     Data
25              3.3     2.15
25              3.3     2.21
25              3.3     2.23
25              3.3     2.26
25              3.3     2.19
25             3.45      2.4
25             3.45     2.37
25             3.45     2.42
25             3.45     2.34
25             3.45     2.35
105             3.3      3.2
105             3.3     3.22
105             3.3     3.23
105             3.3     3.24
105             3.3     3.26
105            3.45     3.33
105            3.45     3.32
105            3.45     3.34
105            3.45      3.3
105            3.45     3.36
```

I would like to calculate the average Data for each Temperature and Voltage case. I could do this in excel by making a pivot table but I would like to learn how to do it in python script so I can automate this data processing part.

Thank you,
Victor

P.S. sorry for the weird format table. I'm not exactly sure how to correctly copy and paste a table in here.

Comment: I am not sure to understand, you want the average of the data column? or the average of the data column every time they are different case (Data average for T=25 and V=3.3 for instance)?

Comment: Look into using the Pandas package, which has handy pivot and pivot table functions

Comment: If your are averaging by both temperature and voltage see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165629/pandas-pivot-table-for-multiple-columns-at-once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the function you need is `.groupby()` if you are familiar with it:

```
df.groupby(['Temperature','Voltage'])['Data'].mean()
```

This will generate a mean value of the value `Data` for each unique `Temperature` and `Voltage` combination. This is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'Temperature': [25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,105,105,105,105,105,105,105,105,105,105],
    'Voltage': [3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.45,3.45,3.45,3.45,3.45,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.45,3.45,3.45,3.45,3.45],
    'Data': [2.15,2.21,2.23,2.26,2.19,2.4,2.37,2.42,2.34,2.35,3.2,3.22,3.23,3.24,3.26,3.33,3.32,3.34,3.3,3.36]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.groupby(['Temperature','Voltage'])['Data'].mean())
```

Output:

```
Temperature  Voltage
25           3.30       2.208
             3.45       2.376
105          3.30       3.230
             3.45       3.330
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that is what I was looking for. I have a question, if i wanted to iterate through each data point of each Voltage and Temperature and do something like take a abs value difference between 2 points and see if it is greater than a certain number, if it is, then count that as a jump. How would I do that?